# restkit propertyname not showing

Tags: ios, mapping, nsarray, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having problems when posting to my server. Every value is being parsed expect the property-names of my array aren't.

My server is expecting something like this:

> {
>      "location": 2,
>      "_id": "517808546b496658c10209",
>      "products": [
>       {
>         "amount": 3,
>          "total": 6.6,
>          "name": "Coke",
>          "price": 2.2
>        },{
>         "amount": 1,
>          "total": 4.0,
>          "name": "Water",
>          "price": 2
>        }
>      ]
>    }

but my client is sending this:

> {
>      "location": 2,
>      "_id": "517808546b496658c10209",
>      "products": [
>         3,
>         6.6,
>         "Coke",
>         2.2,
>         1,
>         4.0,
>         "Water",
>         2
>      ]
>    }

Product:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) float price; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) Category *category; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) int amount; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) float total;
```

my code:

```
RKObjectMapping *productMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[productMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"productId":@"_id",@"amount":@":amount",@"total":@"total",@"price":@"price",@"name":@"name"}];

RKObjectMapping *horecaMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[horecaMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Id": @"_Id",@"deliverySpotId":@"location"}];

[horecaMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"self.getBasketSet" toKeyPath:@"products" withMapping:productMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:horecaMapping objectClass:[Horeca class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/plain"];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager postObject:sharedHoreca path:@"/orders" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

--update 1--
I also tried to make an NSSET of my array but this still doesn't help me. 
[(nsarray to nsset restkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556090/restkit-0-20-post-array-json-issues)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log?

Comment: No I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

The `self.getBasketSet` key path is giving me pause -- what is that returning? If your `sharedHoreca` object returns an `NSArray` of objects responding to the key paths specified then it should do what you are expecting...

Comment: I tried with returning an NSArray and NSSet but my keys still won't show up. My self.getBasketSet is just a simple array or set with objects of type Product.        

    property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;  
    property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail;  
    property (nonatomic, assign) float price;  
    property (nonatomic, strong) Category *category;  
    property (nonatomic, assign) int amount;  
    property (nonatomic, assign) float total;